# Attached Behavior on ButtonBase to do something before the Click event is fired for others?

Tags: wpf

Is there any way I can wire up an attached behavior based on the `ButtonBase` class where I could do something **before** any other subscribers to the `Click` event are notified?

From my current understanding of events and RoutedEvents I would say no but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RegisterClassHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522486.aspx) to add a handler that will be called before all other instance handlers.  I realize this is not an "attached behavior".

Comment: this is brilliant and scary at the same time :)

Comment: regarding attached behavior: in combination with a simple attached property it can quickly become one :)